Query that returns the majority verdict of reviews and the percent of that majority
My tables:
TblFruits:



id
name




1
apple



TblReview:



reviewID
verdict
fruitID
userID
datePosted




2
Delicious
1
1
2024-12-09 00:00:00


3
Awful
1
1
2024-12-07 00:00:00


5
Delicious
1
2
2024-12-09 00:00:00


6
Delicious
1
3
2024-12-09 00:00:00


7
Awful
1
4
2024-12-09 00:00:00



The output of my final query needs to look like this:



fruit name
Verdict
%




apple
Delicious
75



I need to return a single row containing the majority verdict of the reviews and the percent of reviews that lead to that verdict.
Catch
Users can post multiple reviews for the same fruit, in which case only the latest review will be counted
Unfortunately I only got as far as joining the tables
select 
    name as 'fruit name', 
    tbReview.verdict, tbReview.userID as 'reviewed by', tbReview.datePosted
from
    tbFruits
left join 
    tbReview on tbFruits.fruitId = tbReview.fruitID
group by 
    tbReview.userID, tbReview.datePosted, tbFruits.name, tbReview.verdict


Does it need to handle multiple fruit types? If so what would the desired result be?

And can the verdict truly be free text? Or specific values?

Mostly similar to the above answer,should work if you had other fruits in the tables.

CTE latestreviews - Filters out only the most recent review for each user and fruit using ROW_NUMBER()
CTE verdictcounts - Counts the number of occurrences of each verdict for each fruit based on the most recent review of each user.
CTE totalreviews Counts the total number of recent reviews for each.
fruit.

EDIT : Code updated to work with multiple fruits
Fiddle
with latestreviews as (
select 
    r.fruitid,
    r.verdict,
    row_number() over (partition by r.userid, r.fruitid order by r.dateposted desc) as rn
from tblreview r
),
verdictcounts as (
    select 
        r.fruitid,
        r.verdict,
        count(*) as verdict_count
    from latestreviews r
    where r.rn = 1  
    group by r.fruitid, r.verdict
),
totalreviews as (
    select 
        r.fruitid,
        count(*) as total_reviews
    from latestreviews r
    where r.rn = 1  
    group by r.fruitid
),
rankedverdicts as (
    select 
        vc.fruitid,
        vc.verdict,
        vc.verdict_count,
        tr.total_reviews,
        row_number() over (partition by vc.fruitid order by vc.verdict_count desc) as rank
    from verdictcounts vc
    join totalreviews tr on vc.fruitid = tr.fruitid
)
select
    f.name as fruit_name,
    rv.verdict,
    cast((rv.verdict_count * 100.0 / rv.total_reviews) as decimal(5, 2)) as percentage
from rankedverdicts rv
join tblfruits f on f.id = rv.fruitid
where rv.rank = 1
order by rv.fruitid;

Output


Thank you. still wont work with multiple fruits. But I got it to work with a few tweaks

Hey, I just updated the code to work with multiple fruits, See the EDIT section, think you got it working already :)

Use row_number() & over() to determine "the most recent" response per user per fruit, then calculate percentages, and finally output the TOP (1) WITH TIES which will cater for 50/50 results to show both verdicts:
WITH LatestReviews
AS (
    SELECT
         fruitID
        , userID
        , verdict
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY fruitID
            , userID ORDER BY datePosted DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM TblReview
    )
    , VerdictCounts AS (
    SELECT
         fruitID
        , verdict
        , COUNT(*) AS verdict_count
        , COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY fruitID) AS verdict_percentage
    FROM LatestReviews
    WHERE rn = 1
    GROUP BY
          fruitID
        , verdict
    )
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
      fruitID
    , verdict AS majority_verdict
    , verdict_percentage AS majority_percentage
FROM VerdictCounts
ORDER BY
      fruitID
    , verdict_count DESC
    , verdict

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/OALtLK81

row_number() over(PARTITION BY fruitID, userID ORDER BY datePosted DESC for each fruit for each person (that's what the "partition" means) assign the integer 1 to the "most recent" row (that's what the descending order by date does)
the next CTE selects only the rows where that integer (column rn) is 1  hence only the "most recent" rows are considered when calculating verdicts and percentages
the final select uses TOP (1) WITH TIES so that any results where the  "highest percentage" is on e one row, or shared over more than 1 row, then all "top results" will be returned by the query.


Nice one! I have this bad feeling OP is going to come back and want to handle multiple fruit... but oh well.

Thank you for your reply. let me just review it for a while. This is a lot to take in for me and I really want to understand it

some additional notes on logic used have been added, hopefully this will help

We can accomplish that as follows:

Use a CTE to filter out reviews which shouldn't be counted
Group the counts
Work out the percentages and only show the top 1.

with cte1 as (
  -- Determine which reviews are valid
  select *
    , row_number() over (partition by UserId, FruitId order by DatePosted desc) rn
  from Review
), cte2 as (
  -- Filter out invalid reviews and count the remaining reviews
  select count(*) Votes, FruitId, Verdict
  from cte1
  where rn = 1
  group by FruitId, Verdict
)
-- Display the top result and percentage
select top 1 f.Name [Fruit Name], Verdict
  , convert(decimal(9, 2), 100.00 * Votes / sum(Votes) over ()) [%]
from cte2 r
join Fruit f on f.FruitId = r.FruitId
order by [%] desc;

Returns



Fruit Name
Verdict
%




Apple
Delicious
75.00



db<>fiddle
Note: This only works for a single fruit as per your example. If you wanted to handle multiple fruit you would need to clarify your desired results.

Thank you for your reply. let me just review it for a while. This is a lot to take in for me and I really want to understand it
